# DataFrame object is not callable when sharing a variable between functions

Tags: python, pandas

This line is causing an error: `SKU_Metrics = SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)`.
The error I get is `Dataframe object is not callable`. Basically, I want to do this pattern where I call the `SAS_full_dataset()` function within functions, store that as a variable and do transformations on those variables in those functions. Notice I put the function as parameters in the functions I want to call that function in. I think this is a sensible approach. What puzzles me here too is that the code doesn't error out in some places, like `SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()`

I can't figure out why I am getting this error. In the code below, some file import assignments were left out of this code to for length sake.

```py
def data_cleaning_and_filtering(SAS_current_period,SAS_prior_period,primary_vendor):
    ## filtering out OT,LT Verticals
    SAS_current_period = SAS_current_period.loc[(SAS_current_period['Vertical Code'] != 'LT') & (SAS_current_period['Vertical Code'] != 'OT' )]
    SAS_prior_period = SAS_prior_period.loc[(SAS_prior_period['Vertical Code'] != 'LT') & (SAS_prior_period['Vertical Code'] != 'OT' )]

    ## filtering out CustTypes UPS, S&S Latam, S&S Canada
    SAS_current_period = SAS_current_period.loc[(SAS_current_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'NT') & (SAS_current_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'GH' ) & (SAS_current_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'NJ' )]
    SAS_prior_period = SAS_prior_period.loc[(SAS_prior_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'NT') & (SAS_prior_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'GH' ) & (SAS_prior_period['Customer Type Code'] != 'NJ' )]

    ## filtering out negative quantities and Revenue
    SAS_current_period = SAS_current_period.loc[(SAS_current_period['Qty Shipped'] > 0) & (SAS_current_period['Ext. Sell Price'] > 0)]
    SAS_prior_period = SAS_prior_period.loc[(SAS_prior_period['Qty Shipped'] > 0) & (SAS_prior_period['Ext. Sell Price'] > 0)]

    ## filtering to shipBR = 01
    SAS_current = SAS_current_period.loc[(SAS_current_period['Ship Br.'] == 1)]
    SAS_prior = SAS_prior_period.loc[(SAS_prior_period['Ship Br.'] == 1)]

    ## dropping/Excluding SKU's where primary vendor = 1708 (Midwest)
    primary_vendor['SKU'] = primary_vendor['PRDLIN'] + '-' + primary_vendor['PRODNO']
    exclude_list = primary_vendor.loc[(primary_vendor['VENDNO'] == 1708),['SKU']]
    #SAS_current = SAS_current_period.drop(SAS_current_period[SAS_current_period.SKU.isin(exclude_list[:])].index)
    #SAS_prior = SAS_prior_period.drop(SAS_prior_period[SAS_prior_period.SKU.isin(exclude_list[:])].index)

    return SAS_current,SAS_prior
```

The overall goal through the next handful of functions is to build sections of the overall sp1 file in blocks, then join them in a final function at the end to return the full sp1 adjustment file.

This is a function to join the base and current period invoice datasets, because we only want to make recommendations on SKU's that have been bought in the last year.

```py
def SAS_full_dataset():
    SAS_current,SAS_prior = data_cleaning_and_filtering(SAS_current_period,SAS_prior_period,primary_vendor)
    SAS_full_dataset = pd.concat([SAS_current, SAS_prior])
    SAS_full_dataset['Invoiced Date'] = pd.to_datetime(SAS_full_dataset['Invoiced Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset.sort_values(by='Invoiced Date',ascending=False)
    return SAS_full_dataset
```

here we are putting together the SKU details tab of the adjustment table

```py
def SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset):
    SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()
    SAS_full_dataset = pd.merge(SAS_full_dataset,AVG_cost[['SKU','inventory code']],how='left',on='SKU')
    SKU_Details=SAS_full_dataset
    SKU_Details = pd.merge(SKU_Details,AVG_cost[['SKU','inventory code']],how='left',on='SKU')
    SKU_Details = SAS_full_dataset[['Tracking Ln','PCAT','SKU','inventory code']]
    SKU_Details['Tracking Ln|PCAT'] = SKU_Details['Tracking Ln']+'|'+SKU_Details['PCAT']
    SKU_Details = SKU_Details.drop_duplicates(subset='SKU')
    return SKU_Details
```

```py
# this function returns the the dataframe associated with the 'sku metrics' tab of
# the sp1 adjustment file 
def SKU_Metrics(SAS_full_dataset):
    # doing aggregate calculation on base dataset. keep in mind this dataset has been filtered
    SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()
    SAS_full_dataset['Ext. Sell Price'].astype(float).inplace=True
    SAS_full_dataset['TTM']=SAS_full_dataset.groupby(['SKU'])['Ext. Sell Price'].transform('sum')
    
    # creating SKU metrics tabs
    SKU_Metrics = SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)
    SKU_Metrics = pd.merge(SKU_Metrics,SAS_full_dataset[['SKU','TTM Revenue']],how='left',on='SKU')
    
    Historical_SP1['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Historical_SP1['Effective Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    Historical_SP1.sort_values(['Effective Date'],ascending=False).groupby('SKU').inplace=True
    current_period_sp1 = Historical_SP1.drop_duplicates(subset='SKU',keep='first')
    base_period_sp1 = np.where(Historical_SP1['Effective Date'].isin(base_period),base_period_sp1)
    return SKU_Metrics
    
SKU_Metrics = SKU_Metrics(SAS_full_dataset)
```

The traceback is the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\mstevens\python_test _Copy_for_pricing\python_sns\pricing_test_docs\Sp1 Adjustment June23.py in line 141
    145     base_period_sp1 = np.where(Historical_SP1['Effective Date'].isin(base_period),base_period_sp1)
    146     return SKU_Metrics
--> 148 SKU_Metrics = SKU_Metrics(SAS_full_dataset)

c:\Users\mstevens\python_test _Copy_for_pricing\python_sns\pricing_test_docs\Sp1 Adjustment June23.py in line 133, in SKU_Metrics(SAS_full_dataset)
    138 SAS_full_dataset['TTM']=SAS_full_dataset.groupby(['SKU'])['Ext. Sell Price'].transform('sum')
    139 # creating SKU metrics tabs
--> 140 SKU_Metrics = SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)
    141 SKU_Metrics = pd.merge(SKU_Metrics,SAS_full_dataset[['SKU','TTM Revenue']],how='left',on='SKU')
    142 Historical_SP1['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Historical_SP1['Effective Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

c:\Users\mstevens\python_test _Copy_for_pricing\python_sns\pricing_test_docs\Sp1 Adjustment June23.py in line 115, in SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)
    121 def SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset):
--> 122     SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()
    123     SAS_full_dataset = pd.merge(SAS_full_dataset,AVG_cost[['SKU','inventory code']],how='left',on='SKU')
    124     SKU_Details=SAS_full_dataset

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: ya so this whole thing is code except the top and bottom bits. i clearly butchered writing this post and cant salvage it by editing it, my bad. sorry for it being so unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SKU_Details=SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)
```

After executing this line, `SKU_Details` isn't a function anymore.

You've reassigned the name `SKU_Details` to be the value that was *returned* from the function call, in this case a Dataframe object.

Comment: ya, sorry that line should be commented out. thats only there to test the function output. i accidently uncommented that line making the post. I greatly appreciate your feedback, but the error still stands

Comment: but ya, the variable assignments after the functions are just to test the function outputs

Comment: correction, the error goes back as far as this line'SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()' in 'SKU_details' function

Comment: Saying "oh that line should be commented out" does not help.  All I can do is to **look at the code you posted**.  It's your job to make sure the code in the question **matches the real code you are actually using**.

Comment: again sorry about that, John. I appreciate your time I updated the code in the post to reflect what im actually running. I kept the last assignment line in and am running the file up until that line.  after running the file with the code just as it is above, it errors out in these 3 places:          def SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset):
--   SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()    AND                                                
        SKU_Metrics =SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)     AND finally-> SKU_Metrics = SKU_Metrics(SAS_full_dataset)

Comment: @padawan Please update the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: @padawan What do you mean "it errors out in these three places"?  The first error will stop the program, so how would it proceed to the next two errors??

Comment: noted. the traceback is in the comment above. ultimately it traceback here: def SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset):
--> 122     SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()

Comment: traceback added to body of post

Comment: Okay, so you've made a very similar error.  At the top of the `SKU_Metrics()` function, you assign `SAS_full_dataset = SAS_full_dataset()`, which recreates the name `SAS_full_dataset` as a _new local variable_ inside the function.  But then a few lines later you call `SKU_Metrics = SKU_Details(SAS_full_dataset)`, and inside _that_ function, you try to call `SAS_full_dataset()` as if it were a function, which it isn't.

Comment: Basically, why do you insist on making new variables with the same name as your functions?  Don't do that!  Give them different names.

Comment: your a stud, thanks so much for helping me with this and putting up with my incompetance. I knew that its a no-no to name variables and functions the same, but thought i had it sorted out so it didnt matter. really nice catch there on what the error was. have a great day, and rest assured, you made a big difference for me!